# Visual Studio for Mac Wraps Lines Conflict in AndroidManifest.xml File

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

My coworkers who use Visual Studio for Windows have a line wrap in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However, it is unwrapped while coding in Visual Studio for Mac. Even if I undo the change, Visual Studio for Mac will kick it and unwrap the line again. [image]

I have disabled all the checkboxes for Analysis and Intellisense that apply to Android XML. Still the situation remains. Can someone please give me some pointers as to how to force Visual Studio for Mac to leave things as they are? Thank you for your help! [image]

Comment: On default, your Visual Studio for Mac will open the manifest file in Android Manifest Editor mode. I would suggest that you only push the manifest file to the repo when the content of it changes.